# How to draw on a JPanel using Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel

I am working on a project and i have already made a menu and a `JPanel` but now i want to draw over the `JPanel` and add some HUD to my game.

I am providing a picture with the final panel of my game and i want to add at the left a blue rectangle with the player heads and at the right another rectangle with actions, money etc but i want to construct them outside my Window class where i construct the frame and all of the JPanels. Generally now that the player has chosen to play a local game i want to be able to draw and erase on this panel as the game continues.
[image]

```
private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrategy(1);
        return;
    }
    
    Graphics g = null;
    
    window.render();
    if (gameState == STATE.MultiPlay) {
        handler.render(g);
        hud.render(g);
    }
    if (gameState == STATE.LocalPlay) {
        handler.render(g);
        hud.render(g);
    }
}
```

The code i provided is the render method i am using at my game engine class. With my game engine i have made this method circles 10 times per second and i wanted from here to instantiate the `Graphics` class and then go on with the other class and rendering everything i want to draw over that `JPanel`.

How can i draw over that `JPanel` using `Graphics` or something like that?

Comment: *How can i draw over that JPanel using Graphics* - well our posted code is using a BufferedStrategy which implies you are using a Canvas, not a JPanel so I'm not really understanding your question. If you use the Canvas, then you just add your painting code to your other painting logic. So you need to add "properties" to you class to control what you do or don't paint. If you are using Swing, don't know if this will help but you can check out [How to Decorate Component with JLayer Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)

Comment: Check out the Oracle tutorial [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: The problem is that using the canvas does not work so thats why i am asking this question

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code the data to draw. 2) Tip: Add @camickr (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @Kamora *using the canvas does not work* and you have been given a link to the Swing tutorial on how to do custom painting on  a JPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use Graphics object like that:

```
Graphics g= bs.getDrawGraphics();
```

I think it will be usefull, have a nice day.

PD: If you don't want to do that, you can also override the method paint(Graphcis g) and use the parameter.

Comment: I had it like that before but it did not work... I did some more research and i think that the problem is that the thread running for the Swing class and thread i have for my game engine do not communicate so the Graphics can not draw on the JPanel... Although i am not very sure if thats the case.